# Retrieving many columns from SQL table but I want to bound selective columns with gridview control

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am asp.net learner.
Consider I have a table "customer" which has columns 1-eid,2-ename,3-edept,4-esal,5-edesignation..
I want to retrieve all these columns but I want to show only eid,ename and edesignation in gridview.

How can I display those selective columns in gridview control.
I just know how to  display all the coulms from result of a query. But I don't know how to display selective columns.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you retrieving columns that you won't show?

Comment: I need other columns values bcoz I m going to use those values for others reasons (as my project requirement).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must turn off AutoGenerateColumns and create the bound fields in the markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCustomers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowHeader="true" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="eid" HeaderText="ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ename" HeaderText="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="edesignation" HeaderText="Designation " />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

If you want to have access to `edept` and `esal` in code-behind, you can add these fields to the `DataKeyNames` attribute of the GridView.